# Which version of Subversion do I need to use with Apache Http Server 2.2.x?

Tags: apache, svn, tortoisesvn, version

I need to install the correct version of "Apache subversion" to get it running and work with Apache webserver 2.2.x  according to the following page [http://augusttown.blogspot.com](http://augusttown.blogspot.com/2010/02/setup-http-based-svn-repository-with.html) But one of the [subversion.tigris.org](http://subversion.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=8100;) to the page seems to be not available and I really need to know which subversion I have to use.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Subversion project is no more on Tigris, see http://subversion.apache.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of the current 1.6.x or 1.7.x variants should work fine with Apache 2.2.x